# FreeNAS - FAMP (for Piwigo): PHP extension "mysqli" is not loaded

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to install Piwigo which requires an operational FAMP. I've largely followed the excellent guide by Samuel Dowling (https://www.samueldowling.com/2020/...n-freenas-iocage-jail-with-hardened-security/) on installing Nextcloud to get the FAMP base running.
It all looks rahter operational (I can access the server and load the PHP info webpage page to demonstrate that PHP is also operational).
So next step is, like for NextCloud, to run, via the webpage a script to configure Piwigo. on a browser, I type `192.168.1.80/` => it finds it has to access `192.168.1.80/install.php`, but displays a page saying:
**Piwigo encountered a non recoverable error**
PHP extension "mysqli" is not loaded

Mysqli is installed.
`php -r 'phpinfo();' |grep mysqli` gives the following output:

```
mysqli
mysqli.allow_local_infile => Off => Off
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
root@Piwigo:/ # php -v
PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2020 01:11:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.34, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

`php -m` gives the following output:

```
[PHP Modules]
apcu
bcmath
bz2
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
gd
gmp
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
posix
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

I can see 'mysqli' appears and is loaded, so not sure what is missing for Piwigo.....
Could anybody give me a hint as to where to look ?

Many thanks in advance !
(Config: FreeNAS 11.2. All above installed in a dedicated jail)